# After she had completed her home work, she went to bed

Tags: tense, past-vs-past-perfect

> After she had completed her home work, she went to bed.

Is the sentence correct or not? Is it **had completed** or **have completed**?

Comment: What do think should be the correct choice?

Answer (score 1):

> **After she had completed her home work, she went to bed**
>
> **After she has /have completed her home work she went to bed**

The  firstsentence is correct.There are two past actions here.The first one may be in the past perfect and the second one may be in the simple past.

.The second  sentence is wrong 
if you use have or even has. You can not use present perfect since it may refer to a completed activity in the present moment.

You may say:

> **She went to bed after she completed her home work.**

The conjunction after indicates that she completed her home work first and later she went to bed.

Comment: OP provides no evidence of any research they did to solve their query. There are plenty of questions in ELL that discuss the use of tenses - had OP looked into those their problem would be resolved. Or, OP could have mentioned which ones they looked at and why those questions did not help them. OP's question looks like a homework question - which we should not answer unless their is a major concern or a real problem. The point is to empower non-natives to learn and educate themselves on simple problems. We should do that by asking them questions to make them think.

Comment: You giving away the right answer does more harm than good to OP. They have gotten the correct answer, but they have not truly learnt why that is the correct answer. They will not put in the effort now. That is why I made a comment as to which they thought is correct - this will make them think. This will make them put in just a bit more effort into first trying to find their own answers.